# Audit of 1 entity with 3 relationships causes error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I am auditing an entity called Form, it has a relationship with two other entities, but the method it implements is annotated with transactional, thus reviewing only one entity, if I remove the transactional it will go, but if there is an error when saving any of the entities what has already been saved is not undone.

Being able to save the form by auditing its relationships without interfering with the transaction